# Update of PlayN from 1.0.1 to 1.0.3 in Eclipse

Tags: playn

I installed PlayN 1.0.1 two or three months ago. 
Now, I would like to 'migrate' to 1.0.3. 
[reason for the migration: I want to fix that in java callbacks are not asyncronous in 1.0.1]

I already created a clone from https://code.google.com/p/playn-samples . 
But now, I don't know how to go on. 
I have my projects in eclipse with maven dependencies like playn- 
core-1.0.1.jar which are in *.jars like 
C:/Users//.m2/repository/com/googlecode/playn/playn-core/1.0.1/ 
playn-core-1.0.1-sources.jar 
How can I replace them with my *1.0.3.jars? 
Thank you!

Comment: Do you use maven in you project? if yes, simply change you playn dependency from 1.0.1 to  1.0.3 in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you created your game using the Maven archetype, then you will have a top-level `pom.xml` file in your project. In that `pom.xml` file, you will see a `<properties>` section that contains:

```
<playn.version>1.0.1</playn.version>
```

Assuming you have not made any custom changes to your project POM files, you can simply change the above to 1.0.3.

If you copied one of the sample projects and reworked it as the basis of your own project, you should also have the same `<playn.version>` property in your top-level `pom.xml` file.

Assuming that you imported your project into Eclipse using the **Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects**, then Eclipse will now give you a warning that your projects are out of date with their POM files. You can right click on your project in Eclipse and select **Maven -> Update Project Configuration**. Then everything will be updated to the latest version.